# Components method only called once at start

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-scheduled

I have s Spring Component. How can I call a method only one at start and never again?

I use Scheduler but I am only aware of periodically calls.

Sure I can set the interval very high - but maybe there is a better solution for my problem.

```
@Component
public class Test
{
    @Scheduled (fixedDelay = 100000)
    public void foo ()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the @PostConstruct annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to handle this; PostConstruct is the most straightforward.

You just add a PostConstruct annotation to your method, dropping the `@Scheduled` annotation altogether.  Spring will execute this method after it creates the bean and is done initializing it.

```
@PostConstruct
public void foo ()
{
}
```